# Python youtube search how to get "link"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

ı am trying to write a program to search anything on youtube after ı want to open the first page.
with webbrowser module.

```
from youtube_search import YoutubeSearch
import webbrowser


results = YoutubeSearch('eminem', max_results=10).to_json()

print(results)
```

and this lines gives me;

```
{"videos": [{"title": "Eminem - Venom", "link": "/watch?v=8CdcCD5V-d8", "id": "8CdcCD5V-d8"}, {"title": "Eminem - Lose Yourself [HD]", "link": "/watch?v=_Yhyp-_hX2s", "id": "_Yhyp-_hX2s"}, {"title": "Eminem - Without Me (Official Video)", "link": "/watch?v=YVkUvmDQ3HY", "id": "YVkUvmDQ3HY"}, {"title": "Eminem - Rap God (Explicit) [Official Video]", "link": "/watch?v=XbGs_qK2PQA", "id": "XbGs_qK2PQA"}, {"title": "Eminem - Not Afraid (Official Video)", "link": "/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s", "id": "j5-yKhDd64s"}, {"title": "Eminem - Mockingbird (Official Music Video)", "link": "/watch?v=S9bCLPwzSC0", "id": "S9bCLPwzSC0"}, {"title": "Eminem - When I'm Gone (Official Music Video)", "link": "/watch?v=1wYNFfgrXTI", "id": "1wYNFfgrXTI"}, {"title": "Eminem - Cleanin' Out My Closet (Official Video)", "link": "/watch?v=RQ9_TKayu9s", "id": "RQ9_TKayu9s"}, {"title": "Eminem - Till I Collapse [HD]", "link": "/watch?v=ytQ5CYE1VZw", "id": "ytQ5CYE1VZw"}, {"title": "Eminem - Love The Way You Lie ft. Rihanna", "link": "/watch?v=uelHwf8o7_U", "id": "uelHwf8o7_U"}]}
```

now, how can ı reach to "link" to open the song?
ı tried this but gives me error.

```
a = results.get("link")
webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com/" + "a")
```

which is;

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

how can ı fix this problem? why results variable is str object why is not dictionary? where is my mistake?

and also ı am working on Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are converting the results to a JSON string. Don't do that. Instead, call `to_dict()` to get the results as a Python dictionary:

```
results = YoutubeSearch('eminem', max_results=10).to_dict()
for v in results:
    print('https://www.youtube.com' + v['link'])
```

Note:

In a more recent version as of August 2022, the `'link']` key is changed to `'url_suffix'`.

[See the source code](https://github.com/joetats/youtube_search/blob/master/youtube_search/__init__.py)

Comment: @Canİlgu My original answer was based on some incorrect assumptions. The general concept is correct, though: don't do more work than you need to. You already have a python data structure, don't serialize it into JSON. Refresh the page for updated code.

Comment: yeap ı tried but gives me error;

 for v in results['videos']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

   btw thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `for v in results:` instead of `for v in results['videos']:`, then it should work.

Comment: @Ahmet Thanks. I assumed the JSON returned by `to_json()` and the dict returned by `to_dict()` have the same shape.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes interestingly `to_dict()` returns a list... Some form of trap by the modules author i presume.

Comment: @Ahmet Hard to tell if that's intentional or the result of iterating behavior over the lifetime of the project.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because is a string not a dictionary.  You need to convert it to a dictionary to use the get method.

Here is some simple code to get started:

```
from youtube_search import YoutubeSearch
import json

results = YoutubeSearch('eminem', max_results=10).to_json()
results_dict = json.loads(results)
```

Now, you are going to return 10 results and you want the links for each song (or channel).

```
for v in results_dict['videos']:
    print('https://www.youtube.com' + v['link'])
```

If you want to see more, use the `type` function:

`type(results)` and `type(results_dict)` results in different output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! now i understood better. :)

Comment: Why convert the results to JSON and then parse them? This is extra, unnecessary work. You should be able to use `YoutubeSearch` more directly to do this instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, you are right!  But worthwhile to play with the type function.  Also, gotta answer quick to avoid getting sniped.